# CSS position: same classes, different positions

Tags: css, position

I'm getting crazy with this problem: why does the second "socialHighlights" div is not aligned with the first? I noticed that if I take out the div with  the roundedVisited class, it woks fine... What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

**THE CSS:**

```
.roundedVisited{
background-color: pink; padding:2px; padding-left: 5px;  padding-right: 5px;  }

.outerHighlightBox
{
position: relative; width: 180px; background-color: #eee;
    }


.socialHighlights
{
position: relative; height: 25px; width: 168px; padding: 6px 2px 2px 10px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px; background-color: #ccc;
    }
```

**THE HTML CODE:**

```
<div class='outerHighlightBox' style='margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 25px;'>
    <div class='socialHighlights' style='margin-left: 0px; '>
        <div style=' float: left; margin-right: 5px; position: relative;'>1st icon</div>
        <div style='float: left;' id='liIcon2'>2nd Icon</div>
        <div class='roundedVisited' style='float: right;'>51</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class='outerHighlightBox' style='margin-left: 190px; margin-top: 25px;'>
    <div class='socialHighlights' style='margin-left: 0px; '>
        <div style=' float: left; margin-right: 5px; position: relative;'>1st icon</div>
        <div style='float: left;' id='Div1'>2nd Icon</div>
        <div class='roundedVisited' style='float: right;'>23</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use float or inline-block on parent containers, and set style out in CSS sheet http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGfnk

Comment: I think I wasn't clear: the divs have to be side by side. Using float or inline-block is not working... Thanks anyway!

Comment: sorry, i still misunderstand , in the link above, they stand side by side as inline-block element, float instead would do the same with different 'side effects'. demo updated with float version as well

Comment: @user3263647 In what way is float or inline-block not working? The codepen looks fine here. On the other hand, you say " if I take out the div with the roundedVisited class, it woks fine." and that is not the case. So I'm afraid there may be some mismatch between what you want, and what you _say_ you want.